# Get week number with POSIX::strftime in perl

Tags: perl, strftime

I need to get the ISO 8601 week number of todays date in perl.

What is wrong woth the following code?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $weekNumber = POSIX::strftime("%V", localtime time);
print $weekNumber, "\n";
```

The output I get is simply `%V` and my expected result (for epoch 1407769639) is `33`.

FYI using `POSIX::strftime("%W", localtime time);` results in `32`.

Comment: Hm Ok, so what might be the problem? I'm running on a Windows machine.

Comment: Prints `%V`. Seems to be a Windows/strftime thing? Found something about only aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ is safe to use under Windows?

Comment: I would consider looking into the DateTime module: http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.10/lib/DateTime.pm#$dt-%3Eweek_number%28%29 ..it has a week_number method too

Comment: @perlsufi: [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) is *enormous*, and an indulgence if all you want is to calculate week numbers. It can really only be justified if you are doing a lot of heavy lifting with dates and times. The algorithm is really simple, and consists primarily of calculating on which day of the week January 1 falls in that year. Week 1 is the first week (Monday to Sunday) that has four days or more in the current year.

Comment: Ah, true. good call :)

Comment: @daker: You should phrase your questions more carefully. I imagine that you wanted to know the *right* way to get the current week number, hence my answer. Ikegami has answered the question that you wrote: *"What is wrong woth the following code?"*

Comment: @Borodin: My question is perfectly clear. I wanted to know why my code failed, hence the topic "...with POSIX::strftime". But thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX functions are thin layers over your C library. What you get is based on your C library's behaviour. You get `%V` because your C library's `strftime` doesn't recognize `%V`.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece), which has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5, and so shouldn't need installing unless you are running a very old version.

`Time::Piece` replaces the core `localtime` function with one that returns a `Time::Piece` object, so the code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print localtime->week, "\n";
```

**output**

```
33
```